# eval-on-export not leaving RESULTS in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

I think I know how to control automatic evaluation of code blocks with the `:exports` keyword and with the `#+call:` tag, but my blocks only leave `#+RESULTS:` when I run them manually via `C-c C-c`.  Is automatic code eval-on-export only for side effects?  Here is a MVE:

```
Here's a source block that executes automatically (modulo security)
when we say ~M-x org-latex-export-to-pdf~

#+name: square
#+header: :var x=0
#+begin_src python :exports code
  return x*x
#+end_src

It seems to execute automatically because of the following
~#+call~ tag: if I remove the tag, the code doesn't execute
automatically any more:

#+call: square(7)

In any case, it only leaves a result in the emacs buffer under a
~#+RESULTS:~ tag if I run it manually via =C-c C-c=.  Why
doesn't it leave a result when it runs automatically?  Is automatic
running only for side effects?

Here is a code block that runs automatically only if I say
~:exports both~ or ~:exports results~.

#+name: ftw-python
#+begin_src python :exports both
  return 43
#+end_src

It also doesn't leave a result unless I run it manually.
```

Comment: Yeah, the lack of results section after eval seems confusing. I ran into this issue when i wanted the code block on export to be evaluated, but not exported. After fiddling around a bit, this is what I got: `:results silent :exports results` evals automatically, but doesn't export.